# jquery UI does not apply if the div is appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a little issue with jqueryUI. I noticed that when I append the content to a page, the UI does not seem to take effect. I tried [this](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) example and it seem to work as expected, however when I tried to extend it had no luck.

I have this in my code

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    $('#tabs-1').click(function() {
        $('.boo').load('boo.html');
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
Hello World!

    <div class="boo">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">

  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">

    <p>Some Test</p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I have this in boo.html

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tabb</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">More  </a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">iFinal</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
      First Tab
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
      Second Tab
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
      Final Tab
  </div>
</div>
```

I was expecting to see a tab inside the first tab. But this is what I saw instead

[image]
 Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `.load()` will create lots of duplicate IDs. That's not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add $( ".boo #tabs" ).tabs(); inside your click event after loading the content, because your tabs() function will not work on future elements.

```
$("#tabs").tabs(); //this work only in the first id
$('#tabs-1').click(function() {
    $('.boo').load('boo.html', function() {
        $(this).find("#tabs").tabs(); //after complete load, convert tabs inside .boo
    });
});
```

Edit. Also, you have to name different every set of tabs [** **Fiddle** **](http://jsfiddle.net/UdRLg/1/)

Your boo.html should look more like this (because href=#tabs-1 opens id=tabs-1 so they cannot repeat):

```
<div id="subtabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#subtabs-1">Tabb</a></li>
        <li><a href="#subtabs-2">More  </a></li>
        <li><a href="#subtabs-3">iFinal</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="subtabs-1">
          First Tab
    </div>
    <div id="subtabs-2">
          Second Tab
    </div>
    <div id="subtabs-3">
          Final Tab
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: More specifically, it needs to be in the `.load()` callback function.

Comment: can't have two ids with the same name in one dom

Comment: @VictoriaFrench You can, they only should be on different parents so the selector can be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initalize the tabs on the new content after it lods. Use complete callback of load to do this.
Should also delegate the clcik handler to an element that will always exist. WHen you remove an element, or replace it, any event handlers bound to it are lost.

```
$(document).on('click','#tabs-1',function() {
       $('.boo').load('boo.html', function(){
           /* new content exists now, can run code on it*/
           $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
       });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First issue is that you are naming both tabs using an id. Consider changing them to classes. Then after each DOM change call .tabs() on that class as such:

boo.html

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#booTab1">Tabb</a></li>
     <li><a href="#booTab2">More</a></li>
     <li><a href="#booTab3">iFinal</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="booTab1">First Tab</div>
  <div id="booTab2">Second Tab</div>
  <div id="booTab3">Third Tab</div>
</div>
```

parent code:

```
<div class="tabs" id="tabContainer">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#tabContainerTab1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabContainerTab2">Proin dolor</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabContainerTab3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabContainerTab1">
     <p>Hello World!</p>
     <div class="boo"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="tabContainerTab2"></div>
  <div id="tabContainerTab3"><p>Some Test</p></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
      $( ".tabs" ).tabs();
      $('#tabContainerTab1').click(function() {
         $('.boo').load('boo.html', function () { 
            $('.tabs').tabs();
         });
       });
    });
</script>
```